# R optim: l(0) > u(0). No feasible solution

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to estimate the parameters in a DLM model by Maximum likelihood and therefore I run *optim* to find the set of parameters that maximizes the likelihood (or rather, minimizes the log-likelihood). (Actually, I am using *dlmMLE* from the dlm-package but this calls *optim*).
The optimization routine seem to run OK and converges to a set of parameters. 
However, I get the following message (not shown as an error nor a warning, but nevertheless):

```
l(0) > u(0).  No feasible solution
```

Can anyone tell me exactly what this means?

Trying to insert the set of estimated parameters into my model seem to work, but why do I get this message? And what does l(0) and u(0) refer to??

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
require(dlm)
require(Matrix)

### Reasing in the data (a 15503 x 5 matrix)

buildS2 = function(x) {
    ### Constructing the F-matrix with 8 parameters
    F = matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=5)
    F[1,1] = x[1]; F[2,2] = x[2]
    F[3,3] = x[3]; F[4,4] = x[4]
    F[5, ] = x[5:8]
    ### Constructing the V matrix with 4 unknown parameters.
    LV = matrix(x[11], 5, 5)
    diag(LV) = exp(x[9])
    LV[5,5] = exp(x[10])
    LV[1:4, 5] = rep(x[12], 4); LV[5, 1:4] = x[12]
    LV = nearPD(LV)$mat
    ### Constructing the G matrix with two unknown parameters 
    G = matrix(x[14], 4, 4)
    diag(G) = x[13]
    ### Constructing the W matrix with two unknown parameters
    LW = matrix(x[16], 4, 4)
    diag(LW) = exp(x[15])
    LW = nearPD(LW)$mat
    modS = dlm(FF = F, V = LV, GG = G, W = LW, m0 = rep(0, 4), C0 = diag(4)*100)
    return(modS)
}

fitS2 = dlmMLE(S2_train, parm = rep(1, 16), build = buildS2, hessian = T, control=list(maxit=500, trace=6))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can run it

Comment: I try to fit this model to a set of data called S2_train. I don't know if you can reproduce this without the data, and it is a quite large dataset. But I have edited the post with the code I am trying to run.